# How to customized Json response using WCF service

Tags: ajax, json, wcf

I am trying to return some JSON from a WCF service. This service simply returns some content from my database. I can get the data. However, I am concerned about the format of my JSON. Currently, the JSON that gets returned is formatted like this:

```
{"d":"[{\"Age\":35,\"FirstName\":\"Peyton\",\"LastName\":\"Manning\"},{\"Age\":31,\"FirstName\":\"Drew\",\"LastName\":\"Brees\"},{\"Age\":29,\"FirstName\":\"Tony\",\"LastName\":\"Romo\"}]"}
```

In reality, I would like my JSON to be formatted as cleanly as possible. I believe (I may be incorrect), that the same collection of results, represented in clean JSON, should look like so:

```
Sucess([{"Age":35,"FirstName":"Peyton","LastName":"Manning"},{"Age":31,"FirstName":"Drew","LastName":"Brees"},{"Age":29,"FirstName":"Tony","LastName":"Romo"}])
```

can anyone please suggest me how could i achive this or let me correct if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It normally depends on what and how you are returning data from JSON. If you are returning `String` then it might contain `/` in your string.

But if you are sending custom data, then it will be clean JSON. For example:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class MyData
{
   private int age;
   private String firstName;
   private String LastName;

   [DataMember]
   public int Age
   {
      get
      {
        return age;
      }
      set
      {
        age = value;
      }
   }
   //Apply same for other members
}
```

And suppose this is your operation contract.

```
MyData getData();
```

Hope, this will work.